# loading images in thumbnail

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

**Problem**

I need to display two different images in a row but

- in my code its repeat the first image
- then display the second image in other row

I don't know what wrong with my code.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="dashbordController">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
   <div class="thumbnail" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <img ng-src="{{image.thumbnail}}" alt="{{image.description}}">
   </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="thumbnail" ng-repeat="image in images">
     <img ng-src="{{image.thumbnail}}" alt="{{image.description}}">
    </div>  
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
app.controller("dashbordController",function($scope){
$scope.images = [
 {"thumbnail":"./views/img1.png", "description":"Image 01 description"},
 {"thumbnail":"./views/img2.png", "description":"Image 02 description"},
 {"thumbnail":"./views/img1.png", "description":"Image 03 description"},
 {"thumbnail":"./views/img2.png", "description":"Image 04 description"},
 {"thumbnail":"./views/img1.png", "description":"Image 05 description"}
];

});
```

Comment: it would be better if you could format the code.

Answer (score 0):

our are using two row templates, so every thumbnail is shown on it's own row.

try using this code:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="dashbordController">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6" ng-repeat="image in images">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img ng-src="{{image.thumbnail}}" alt="{{image.description}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I had changed the col class too. With lg it's only for high resolutions.
Hope this does it.